# Are there any Windows alternatives to INetSim?

Tags: tools, dynamic-analysis

I found a tool for Linux called [INetSim](http://www.inetsim.org/about.html) which emulates services such as HTTP HTTPS IRC and many other. It is often used to trick malware. The problem is that INetSim works only on Linux. So I want Windows based tool for Win 7 32bit which is alternative to this ( I prefer a gui one )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a GUI tool, but [FakeNet](http://practicalmalwareanalysis.com/fakenet/) is a good alternative.

> FakeNet is a tool that aids in the dynamic analysis of malicious
>   software.  The tool simulates a network so that malware interacting
>   with a remote host continues to run allowing the analyst to observe
>   the malware’s network activity from within a safe environment.  The
>   goal of the project is to:
>
> ```
> - Be easy to install and use; the tool runs on Windows and requires no 3rd party libraries
> - Support the most common protocols used by malware
> - Perform all activity on the local machine to avoid the need for a second virtual machine
> - Provide python extensions for adding new or custom protocols
> - Keep the malware running so that you can observe as much of its functionality as possible
> - Have a flexible configuration, but no required configuration
> ```

[Mandiant's ApateDNS](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/download/research-tool-mandiant-apatedns) is a good tool for responding with fake DNS response:

> Mandiant ApateDNS is a tool for controlling DNS responses though an
>   easy to use GUI. As a phony DNS server, Mandiant ApateDNS spoofs DNS
>   responses to a user-specified IP address by listening on UDP port 53
>   on the local machine. Mandiant ApateDNS also automatically sets the
>   local DNS to localhost. Upon exiting the tool, it sets back the
>   original local DNS settings.

[image]